# Calling a function from variable

Tags: javascript

```
function makeCounter() {
  let count = 0;
  
  return function() {
    return count++;
  }
}

makeCounter() 

alert(makeCounter()) // alerts the function itself
```

Why can't I call the function like above and make it work?

Why I have to save the function to a variable first like this?

```
function makeCounter() {
  let count = 0;
  
  return function() {
    return count++;
  }
}

let counter = makeCounter()

counter()

alert(counter())
```

What's the difference?

Comment: You have two functions (makeCounter and the function it returns) so need two invocations.

Comment: When you call `makeCounter()` directly, it returns a function that you do nothing with. But when you call `alert(counter())` you had previously defined `counter` to be the return function.

Comment: I believe your question has been well answered. I just wanted to add that if you want `makeCounter` to go into use immediately, maybe you can use [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE#Examples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `makeCounter()` like this, It will be executed of course but this function return a function. Every Javascript function **always return something**, when the keyword `return` isn't present in the function `undefined`.

So in your case, you are implementing the [Module Design Pattern](https://css-tricks.com/implementing-private-variables-in-javascript/#the-module-design-pattern) which allow you to create **PRIVATE** variables which are not visible outside of your function in this case precisely the hidden variable is `count`.

As you wan't to maintain a counter available as many time the function is executer to have the effect of incrementation. You want to return a function which have access to that private variable so the parttern is like this

```
function X() {
     // private data are define here
     let name = "John doe",
     let age = 52;
     
     // public data are define in the return object
     return {
         getName: () => return name,
         setName: (newName) => name = newName
     }
}
```

As you can see you can't access name variable directly after you have executed the  `X` function. but the returned object give you access to an object which have some helpfull method which manipulate private data in the `X` function.

So here you have define the `makeCounter` functon as this function need to keep track of the `counter` that data is same as private inside of the function so the returned function can have access to that private data so when the return function is executed the counter can be increment.

As the counter can be call multiple time you have to same that returned function in a variable so you can call it whenever you want and the `counter` inside of the `makeCounter` function will be updated.

```js
function makeCounter() {
  let count = 0;
  
  return function() {
    return count++;
  }
}

const counter = makeCounter();

console.log(counter()); // log 0
console.log(counter()); // log 1
console.log(counter()); // log 2
console.log(counter()); // log 3
```

But if you don't save the returned function in a variable you'll have to call a function only once and loose the reference to the counter and every time you call the `makeCounter()()` It will be a new reference of counter

```js
function makeCounter() {
  let count = 0;

  return function() {
    return count++;
  }
}


console.log(makeCounter()()); // log 0
console.log(makeCounter()()); // log 0
console.log(makeCounter()()); // log 0
console.log(makeCounter()()); // log 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You are indeed returning a function, and you would like to invoke the returned function, so main function will create the function in return statement but it doesn't invoke, to do that functionality you should invoke the returned function hence u need to store and call it!.
To make it more clear try the function typeof in JavaScript.

Please correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: Should be in comments but im upvoting.

Comment: No code. No code just some wording. But meant it was me who upvoted.

Comment: Hence the upvote. But these are comments. Also you have enough rep to answer just not to upvote.

Answer (score 0):

A function might return a function. As far as I remember, such a design was used to create a stateful function back in the day and is still being used by transpilers to provide support for older Javascript environments.

For example, if you'd like to create a function that returns a number and manipulates the number for later calls. The function should return another function to encapsulate the state of your number, otherwise, it cannot remember the previous value of the number.

So, with that said, let's create a stateful function:

```js
let statefulFunction = () => {
    let number = 0;

    return {
      add(amount = 1) {
        number += 1;
        return number;
      }
    }
  },
  statefulFunctionInstance = statefulFunction();

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', event => {
    event.target.innerText = statefulFunctionInstance.add();
});
```

```html
<button>0</button>
```

I remember using this design to encapsulate functions like `nextSlide` in a slide or something similar. It can be used to store DOM queries, and form values, etc.